# How to implement FRP using implicit parameter?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, reactive-programming, frp

I am studying Martin Odersky's [Principles of Reactive Programming](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_6b7eadf8318c415035a2e5431c63b40c_week9-9.pdf?Expires=1476057600&Signature=UcudFT-vAe113YuW~OFcqlmsEKd1Q5x3S0TlRjdeiZnFgQk~Myh805151pS~TsSDYYumK30KlBpvMNhC~AVUlaeBWW3iw2X~7WnuPjjHFNSiZmGSsxXrz18ADhzBw5ZZQ-vxpDNAsDhLvdMggfMPPlZwjpvMH6kEpceVbpceNJo_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A). When talking about the implementation of a simple FRP framework, he at the beginning gave one that uses `StackableVariable`(i.e. `DynamicVairable`) to keep track of the currently updated signal, which I can understand. But at the end of the slides, he mentioned that a cleaner solution is to use implicit parameter instead of `DynamicVariable`. Could anyone please show me how this can be done?

Comment: I think scala.rx does it this way: https://github.com/lihaoyi/scala.rx/blob/master/scalarx/shared/src/main/scala/rx/Core.scala

Comment: link seems not to be working, I get an access denied message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link to the slides didn't work for me. As I tried googling it, I now use [1](https://github.com/dnvriend/reactive-programming/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/test/week2/frp/Signal.scala) as reference.

The dynamic variable is a thread-local variable that holds the state of what Signal is currently evaluated. This is needed so that the apply method of Signal can access this information. Let's consider the following example code:

```
val a: Signal[Int] = ???
val b: Signal[Int] = ???
val xPlusY: Signal[Int] = Signal(a() + b())
```

Here, when `a()` is called, it adds itself to the list of dependencies to the currently evaluating Signal. As this information is not accessible anywhere else, we basically use a thread-local a.k.a. global variable.

This solution has a few problems. For example, we can also call `a()` if we're not inside any `Signal()`. Also, well, we have to use a global variable.

The solution would be to give this information to `a()` via an implicit argument: We change the signature from

```
Signal[T]#apply(): T
```

to

```
Signal[T]#apply()(implicit triggeredBy: Signal[_])
```

(Note that we'd probably want to use some new type `TriggeredBy` that encapsulates a Signal instead)

This way, the implementation of this method will have access to its originating Signal without a global/thread-local variable.

But now we have to supply this implicit somehow. One option is to also change the signature of the Signal-creation function from

```
def Signal.apply[T](fun: => T): Signal[T]
```

to

```
def Signal.apply[T](fun: Signal[_] => T): Signal[T]
```

Unfortunately, the syntax of our example code has to change then, because we have to supply a function instead of a body:

```
val xPlusY: Signal[Int] = Signal { implicit triggeredBy => a() + b() }
```

There are a few solutions to this problem:

- Wait until implicit function types will have been implemented [2](http://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/12/07/implicit-function-types.html). This probably won't happen anytime soon, but it will allow us to write the `Signal.apply` signature as follows:

  ```
  def Signal.apply[T](fun: implicit Signal[_] => T): Signal[T]
  ```

  and then be able to write `Signal(a() + b())` again.
- Use some macro magic to transform code of the form `Signal(a() + b())` to `Signal.internalApply(implicit triggeredBy => a() + b())` code. This means, that `Signal.apply` is now a macro. This is the road that scala.rx[3](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scala.rx) has gone and it works well from a usage point of view. This also allows us to write `Signal(a() + b())` again.

**Update**: updated link to implicit functions explanation to a more detailed blog artikle

Comment: The implicit function types thing seems to do something strange in Odersky's example. Are you confident that it will also work in the way that you are using it?

Comment: well, as my whole information on this is from watching https://youtu.be/GHzWqJKFCk4?t=47m19s and I didn't find any further information about it and it's nowhere near to be implemented; I'm not sure if this will also work in this example, but it's my understanding that it would or at least should work in this way, too.

Comment: @Jasper-M there's a new blog article by Martin Odersky which makes clear that implicit function types will indeed work as expected (but unfortunately only in dotty); I updated the link in the article

Comment: Yes I just saw it. Very insightful.